# Problem compiling llvm plugin: llvm/Config/llvm-config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I've been trying to compile an `llvm` plugin. I've checked out the source code of `llvm` [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project) and implemented a simple example e.g. based on [this](https://medium.com/@polarply/build-your-first-llvm-obfuscator-80d16583392b) article. Upon compiling against `llvm`, I get the following error:

```
/mnt/d/Cpp/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Compiler.h:18:10: fatal error: llvm/Config/llvm-config.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include "llvm/Config/llvm-config.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I check the `Compiler.h` file and the file that was supposed to be included, I find a very similarly named file: `llvm-config.h.cmake`. Is this an `llvm` bug or am I doing something wrong? Why is the `llvm` code written like this when it seems faulty?

Comment: I just had the same issue and thought I would share the solution that worked for me. I had to build the LLVM sources manually with CMake based on the official installation guide: https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#id7. `cmake <my_llvm_root/llvm> && cd <my_llvm_root/llvm> && cmake --build .`. I only built it, the installation was made by the .exe installer.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you eventually resolve it?

Comment: I resolve it by copy <https://github.com/getsentry/symsynd/blob/master/demangle/llvm/Config/llvm-config.h> to my llvm include directory, and run `g++ -x c \`llvm-config --cflags\` test.c \`llvm-config --ldflags --libs all --system-libs\` -o test` build.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it you need to build it with cmake than you can include <llvm/Config/llvm-config.h> I do not know if this will be the exact path but you can just simply search for the file after building it.

Comment: how to build llvm-config.h.cmake?

Comment: there should be a cmake file or something similar to execute via terminal, but as I understand you use a library in a system directory so you should use <> instead of ""

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you are including the header and lib files directly from the source-code tree and not from the installation tree.

After building LLVM and related tools from source-code, you need to install the build by running:
cmake --install build --config Release
(replace Release by Debug if you built the debug version)

The files will get installed in the folder specified in the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX option or environment variable. After installing, cmake will create the right llvm-config.h file tailored for your system and build configuration.